# QTableView different edit triggers for different columns

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I want to make different triggers for different columns in QTableView. The view watching to the model inherited from QFileSystemModel, in this model there is an additional column, in this column - QComboBox made through a delegate. I set flags in the model `(QFileSystemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable);` and set triggers `TableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::CurrentChanged);` on the view. Everything is cool with QComboBox, but at the same time I would like the first column to be presented in the view (path from QFileSystemModel) not editable in this way, but be available for use by RMB-> rename (the context menu is already prepared)

~bad english

Answer (score 0):

Not best solution, but the solution

View triggers:

```
TableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
m_pFileSystemModel->setReadOnly(false);
```

Model flags:

```
if (index.column() == 4)
return (QFileSystemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
return QFileSystemModel::flags(index);
```

Problem Solution:

```
connect(TableView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged, this, [this]() {
if (TableView->currentIndex().column() == 4)
    m_pTableView->edit(m_pTableView->currentIndex());
});
```